# How do I set conditions from multiple tables in my LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In the query below, I want to return people that meet multiple conditions. Some of the conditions apply to fields in the table containing the people to be returned. The other condition is applied to a different table (EmailAddresses) linked to the main table (People) via PersonId.

```
var t = People.Where(x =>
            x.Type == 102 &&
            x.FirstName == "Bob" &&
            x.LastName == "Williams" &&
                 x.EmailAddresses.Where (ea=> ea.EmailAddress
                                                 == "bob.williams@acme.org")
            )
            .Select(x => x.PersonId)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do understand this right, at least one of them should have that adress? If yes, use the `Any` method:

```
var t = People.Where(x =>
            x.Type == 102 &&
            x.FirstName == "Bob" &&
            x.LastName == "Williams" &&
                 x.EmailAddresses.Any(ea=> ea.EmailAddress
                                                 == "bob.williams@acme.org")
            )
            .Select(x => x.PersonId)
```

`Any` returns true if at least one of the elements of the `IQueryable<T>` fulfills the predicate.

Comment: Correct. The person I want returned must match all four conditions.

Comment: Yup, that's what I got. The question was - what has to be matched in the `EmailAdresses` property? Just one email adress, right? if yes, this will work.

Comment: sorry, yes there should be just one email address

Comment: @Femaref techincally your not calling methods on a IEnumerable<T> but IQueryable<T> when using EF. Difference is that your Any-delegate wont actually execute but only generate an Expression tree when calling on IQuerable

Comment: yes, of course. But an IQueryable is a IEnumerable as well ;)

Comment: yes, but since IQueryable has its own set of extension methods it doesnt matter... only thing you're making use of from IEnumerable when working with IQueryable is to retrieve an Enumerator for looping over its result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with a join, something like this...

```
var t = from p in People
        join e in EmailAddress on p.PersonId equals e.PersonId into pe
        from a in pe.DefaultIfEmpty
        where p.Type == 102 &&
           p.FirstName == "Bob" &&
           p.LastName == "Williams" &&
           a.EmailAddress == "bob.williams@acme.org"
        select p.PersonId
```